# How can I register functions and gearmanworker when doBackground is called?

Tags: php, gearman

**Client:**

```
<?php

$gmclient= new GearmanClient();
$gmclient->addServer();
$gmclient->doBackground("reverse", "this is a test");

echo "done!\n";
```

**Worker:**

```
<?php

echo "Starting\n";

$gmworker= new GearmanWorker();
$gmworker->addServer();
$gmworker->addFunction("reverse", "reverse_fn");

while($gmworker->work()){}

function reverse_fn($job)
{

  $result= strrev($job->workload());

  $fp = fopen('test.txt', 'a');
  fwrite($fp, $result);
  fclose($fp);
  echo "Result: $result\n";
  return $result;
}

?>
```

The problem is that when I call the client nothing happens until I run

```
php worker.php
```

then it writes to the file, but the shell is just stuck at

```
[user@server gearman]$ php worker.php 
Starting
Result: tset a si siht
```

Is there anyway I can make it so that when it calls doBackground, it runs the worker.php file in the background? I also want to make sure this work when gearmand is restarted so that I don't have to run worker.php if the daemon is restarted.

Comment: Take a look at supervisord (http://supervisord.org/) for managing your php scripts. supervisor will do the process management for you, and respawn php scripts in the background if they die.

Comment: @Sachin: You should post your comment as an answer. I have only ever seen PHP scripts interacting with gearman, run as daemons. Even though we use a proprietary process control management system, supervisord appears to be a good fit for managing child processes.

Comment: @Sachin that's exactly what I did. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted as answer from my comment:

Take a look at supervisord ([supervisord.org](http://supervisord.org/)) for managing your php scripts. supervisor will do the process management for you, and respawn php scripts in the background if they die